# Django - admin filter to "Add..." page (Model with more then one FK)

Tags: django, filtering, admin

I am trying to filter the "Test" content according to "Plan" selection in Admin page as described in the attached picture.
[image: Please open this link to see the picture].

I am looking for an easy way to filter the content of "Test" drop list according to the selection of "Plan" drop list.

Thanks for your help, Eran

### While my models looks like:

```
class TestPlan(models.Model):
    test_plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.test_plan_name


class Test(models.Model):
    test_plan = models.ForeignKey(TestPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    test_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    manual_ttc = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    drop_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    test_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ac = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.test_name


class Result(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey(TestPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    result_path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.status
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new change_form_template for the admin by extending the admin_change_form

Write your own custom JS to handle the change event

your_change_form.html

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'path_to_js.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

create the JS file and add in your custom logic.

in your admin.py, tell django to use your custom change_form html

```
class ResultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = '<template_directory/your_change_form.html>'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. could you please explain me how can i retrieve "Plan" drop-down selection with JS?